# how can I add .net user .net roles for my application from IIS?

Tags: asp.net

I am not sure is there any other way to add User for my application othe than using Asp.net Website admistration tool??

Thanx

Answer (score 0):

The other option is to write your own front end to the role and membership providers. The providers have methods to perform all the actions the Website Admin tool performs.

e.g.

```
var user Membership.CreateUser(name, password);
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8t4h2es.aspx for this method.